# ASP.Net and log4Net - Compatible Framework error on adding of Dll

Tags: .net, log4net

I cannot add log4Net as a reference to my new .Net project.  I've researched this, and all the answers say to change the Target framework from ".Net Framework 4 (Client Profile)" to ".Net Framework 4" or some variation.

Well, my project is already ".Net Framework 4".  And I don't even have the Client Profile type in my target framework drop down.

To be clear, I DO have this option on other projects, but just not on the last one that I made.  I can't remember if I made this a new "Project" or "Website" -- I'm assuming I chose "Project" when I made it.

When I try to add log4net, I get this error:

```
"log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" is incompatible with .NET Framework 4

In order to add it you should to change the project's target to a compatible framework first.
```

Yes, even that incorrect grammar is from the message "you should to change"

I'm missing something fundamental, but for the life of me I can't tell between my projects what is different about this one.

Comment: did yuou try adding the reference via `NuGet` and find whats different?

Comment: I just did (per your comment and LWoodyiii's answer).  It worked.  I have no idea what it did differently.  But the project seems happy now.  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you install [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) and let it add the reference for you.  NuGet is a much more standardized way to install components like log4net and keep them up to date.  It kind of unscrews this sort of thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Log4net unfortunately is only [officially supported](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html) for the.Net versions below, but the note below says it should work fine on backward compatible framework versions.  I've had it work on .Net 3.5, but not 4.0 yet.

- Microsoft .NET Framework 1.0 (1.0.3705)
- Microsoft .NET Framework
  1.1 (1.1.4322)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 (2.0.50727)
- Microsoft
  .NET Compact Framework 1.0

  Mono 1.0

  Mono 2.0

Microsoft Shared Source CLI
   1.0 
CLI 1.0

Compatible Note: Due to the .NET frameworks support for
   backward compatibility log4net will
   run on future versions of the
   runtimes listed above.